# jquery check if value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to save last 10 viewed products in cookie and I need to keep only unique values, I mean, not save the same product two or more times, so I use [js-cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and this is my code

```
    function getLastViewedProducts() {
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[1];
    var thirdLevelLocation = pathArray[2];

    if (secondLevelLocation == 'catalog' && typeof thirdLevelLocation != 'undefined' && $("article[id^='node']").length > 0 ) {
        var currentUrl = window.location.href; 
        var currentTitle = $('.node-header h1').html();
        var currentImgUrl = $('.field-items .field-item:first-child a img').attr('src');

        var productsArray = [{ 'url' : currentUrl, 'title' : currentTitle, 'img' : currentImgUrl }]; 

        if (typeof Cookies.get('lastViewedProductsList') == 'undefined') {
         // no cookie
         Cookies.set('lastViewedProductsList', productsArray, { expires: 7 });
        } else {
         // have cookie
         var arr = Cookies.getJSON('lastViewedProductsList');
         if (jQuery.inArray(productsArray, arr)) {
             if( arr.length > 10 ) {
                 arr.shift();
             }
         }
         arr.push( productsArray );
         Cookies.set('lastViewedProductsList', arr, { expires: 7 });
        }
    }
}
getLastViewedProducts();
```

but my check `if (jQuery.inArray(productsArray, arr))` doesn't work here and in array will be added the same values. Why?

Comment: Have you checked to see what `productsArray` and `arr` contain?  Right before you perform the check, do `console.log(productsArray, arr)` and check the javascript console to see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) checks to see if a *single* value is in an array. In the supplied code products array is a single element, and you never add anything to it. It would be better to just declare the single object and wrap it in an array when you set the cookie.

```
var product = {'url':currentUrl,'title':currentTitle,'img':currentImgUrl}; 
...
Cookies.set('lastViewedProductsList', [product],{expires:7});
```

Then you can check to see if the given `product` is in your `lastViewedProductsList`. You will also want to compare a single property in each object since object comparison truths in JavaScript are a little wonky. To do this we can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var lastViewedProductsList = Cookies.getJSON('lastViewedProductsList');
var productInLastViewed = lastViewedProductsList.
    reduce(function(found,lastViewedProduct){
        return found || (product.url === lastViewedProduct.url);
    },false); 
if(productInLastViewed){
....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!